# What is the source directory of the build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following tasks:

```
steps:
- task: MSBuild@1
  displayName: '$(ProjectName) .Net build | Build solution (No need to build test as well)'
  inputs:
    solution: '**/$(ProjectName)/*.csproj'
    msbuildArchitecture: x64
    configuration: Release
    msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    clean: true

steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(ProjectName)'
    Contents: |
     bin/**
     Bundles/**
     Views/**
     appsettings.json
     appsettings.Development.json
     *.txt
     **/wwwroot/favicon-*.png
     **/wwwroot/favicon-*.ico
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Release'
```

For some reason, the copy step fails with:
`##[error]Error: Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\1\a\projectname`

why is that?

My project output structure following a local VS build is something like this:

[image: wwwroot1]
[image: wwwroot2]

The pipeline .Net build step creates directories as follows:

```
Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\nl".
Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\cs".
Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\de".
...
2022-09-21T02:38:30.3292966Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\runtimes\win-arm\native".
2022-09-21T02:38:30.3293353Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp3.1".
2022-09-21T02:38:30.3293727Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\runtimes\win-arm64\native".
2022-09-21T02:38:31.1717424Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\refs".
2022-09-21T02:38:31.1717862Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\refs".
2022-09-21T02:38:31.1718174Z   Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\refs".
```

so i assumed the source would be `D:\a\1\a\projectname` or `SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(ProjectName)'` but thats not working it seems.

My reasoning for this is before the dev upgraded the project to .NET6, in the older asp.NET model, the output was one wwwroot directory and so it would translate in the build log to something like:

`Creating directory "D:\a\1\a\_PublishedWebsites\projectname\Content\...`

so my copy task source would be `SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_PublishedWebsites/$(ProjectName)'` and that normally worked.

but `_PublishedWebsites`no longer appears to be part of .NET6 build output, so im not sure what the source would be now

Answer (score 0):

To be sure about how the build is generating the directory structure, you can add the following task and check the output:

```
steps:
  - task: MSBuild@1
    displayName: '$(ProjectName) .Net build | Build solution (No need to build test as well)'
    inputs:
      solution: '**/$(ProjectName)/*.csproj'
      msbuildArchitecture: x64
      configuration: Release
      msbuildArguments: '/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      clean: true
      
  - powershell: |
      Get-ChildItem $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -Recurse
    displayName: 'Check agent directories'
```

Comment: The directories are basically like the ones i posted from the log: `D:\a\1\a\runtimes`, `D:\a\1\a\refs`, etc.